# How to run Caesar cipher on a file in C

Tags: c, encryption

How do I run a caesar cipher on a text file for example. In C. I get how to work with a string. How would i read the text file and then accept that as the text to run the cipher on?

Comment: First try write a loop that prints out the text 26 ways; one for each cipher choice.

Comment: Caesar cipher implementation in C: https://github.com/hb20007/miscellaneous-programs/tree/master/c-programs/CaesarCipher

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
    {
    int rCode=0;
    char *filePath="theTextFile";
    FILE *fp=NULL;
    struct stat statBuf;
    void *fileContent=NULL;
```

Determine the file size:

```
    if((-1) == stat(filePath, &statBuf))
       {
       rCode=errno;
       fprintf(stderr, "stat() failed.  errno[%d]\n", errno);
       goto CLEANUP;
       }
```

Allocate sufficient memory to hold the file.

```
    fileContent=malloc(statBuf.st_size);
    if(NULL == fileContent)
       {
       rCode=ENOMEM;
       fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed.\n");
       goto CLEANUP;
       }
```

Open the file.

```
    fp=fopen(filePath, "rb");
    if(NULL == fp)
       {
       rCode=errno;
       fprintf(stderr, "fopen() failed.  errno[%d]\n", errno);
       goto CLEANUP;
       }
```

Read the file content into the allocated memory.

```
    if(statBuf.st_size != fread(fileContent, 1, statBuf.st_size, fp))
       {
       rCode=errno;
       fprintf(stderr, "fread() failed.  errno[%d]\n", errno);
       goto CLEANUP;
       }
```

Run the cipher on the memory image of the file content.

```
    CaesarCipher(fileContent);
    ...

CLEANUP:
```

Close the file

```
    if(fp)
       fclose(fp);
```

Free the allocated memory.

```
    if(fileContent)
       free(fileContent);

    return(rCode);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I prob shud have shown the code I have alread but what is CLEANUP?

Comment: @user3555512, 'CLEANUP' is a label used in conjunction with the 'goto' statement.  Generally, using a goto statement in C and C++ is often considered to be "bad programming style"; which is probably correct for C++.  However; unlike C++, C does not have an exception handling mechanism.  In commercial C programming, the use of the 'goto' statement is fairly standard for handling errors.  In the event of an error, this construct allows control to be transferred to a general error handler; rather than duplicating error handling at each possible point of error within the function.